# BaseTemplateId to use in WebTemplate element when creating template based on BLANKINTERNET

Tags: web-template

I am creating a [WebTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/webtemplate-element-web-template) based on BLANKINTERNET.

I know the BaseTemplateId you reference in your web template isnt really used to anything, but still as a best practice should refer to the template that resembles your onet.xml the most, amongst other reasons for later upgrade scenarios.

BaseTemplateId should refer to the webtemp*.xml ID. Since my site collection root template is based on BLANKINTERNET i have two choices as i see it: BLANKINTERNETCONTAINER (id=52) that really just is a dummy entry that uses a provisioning provider to create a hierarchy of sites or BLANKINTERNET (id=53) that does the "real" work.

So far I'm sticking with 53 but would like to hear peoples thought on this.

More info on WebTemplates? Read "Vesku"'s excellent primer [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119071517/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx#stepbystep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. 53 is the "correct" choice IMHO. Remember that the site will always be identified by SharePoint as BLANKINTERNET 53.